# Is it possible to get the height of visible content between the address bar and keyboard in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

[image: Height of visible HTML between address bar and field navigation / keyboard]

Since the height of this area varies from device to device and iOS version, I'm wondering if there is any way to dynamically figure out its height to make this area more useful.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

and then the correct value can be get from window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible since safari 10.0

Answer (score 0):

I would imaging that `$(window).height()` would give you that data because it returns the height of the viewport, unless safari is being very weird/not doing as it should.

Comment: I think unfortunately the keyboard lays overtop of the viewport and does not count as a window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the height of visible content now with the `VisualViewport` api (`window.visualViewport.height`). Seems it's only supported by safari 13 and higher though